# HG Convert not working on local CVS repository

Tags: mercurial, cvs, mercurial-convert

I have been trying to use HG [convert](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension#Converting_from_CVS) to migrate a local CVS repository to HG.  When I run the command...

```
hg convert CATools
```

I see the following message:

"Valid-requests", but got '')

"Valid-requests", but got '')> assuming destination CATools-hg

> initializing destination CATools-hg
>   repository connecting to
>   :sspi:shcgl-egcrizan:2401:/cvsroot
>   Unknown command: `server'
>
> CVS commands are:
>           add          Add a new file/directory to the repository
>           admin        Administration front end for rcs
>           annotate     Show last revision where each line was modified
>           checkout     Checkout sources for editing
>           commit       Check files into the repository
>           diff         Show differences between revisions
>           edit         Get ready to edit a watched file
>           editors      See who is editing a watched file
>           export       Export sources from CVS, similar to checkout
>           history      Show repository access history
>           import       Import sources into CVS, using vendor branches
>           init         Create a CVS repository if it doesn't exist
>           log          Print out history information for files
>           login        Prompt for password for authenticating server
>           logout       Removes entry in .cvspass for remote repository
>           rannotate    Show last revision where each line of module was
>   modified
>           rdiff        Create 'patch' format diffs between releases
>           release      Indicate that a Module is no longer in use
>           remove       Remove an entry from the repository
>           rlog         Print out history information for a module
>           rtag         Add a symbolic tag to a module
>           status       Display status information on checked out files
>           tag          Add a symbolic tag to checked out version of files
>           unedit       Undo an edit command
>           update       Bring work tree in sync with repository
>           version      Show current CVS version(s)
>           watch        Set watches
>           watchers     See who is watching a file (Specify the --help
>   option for a list of other help
>   options) abort: unexpected response
>   from CVS server (expected
>   "Valid-requests", but got '')"Valid-requests", but got '')

Has anybody found a workaround?  I found this article but do not understand how to do this on Windows.

http://blog.edsantiago.com/archives/2009/02/19/#e2009-02-19T19_23_32.txt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please consider using [cvs2hg](http://hg.gerg.ca/cvs2svn) for the conversion.  "hg convert" is known to have problems with nontrivial CVS repositories, for example often silently producing a Mercurial repository whose branch/tag contents do not agree with those in the CVS repository.  Unless you require incremental conversion (and can live with inaccuracies), "hg convert" is not a reliable solution for converting from CVS to Mercurial.

Answer (score -1):

How "local" is local? If you have filesystem access to the CVS repository, you can just copy it over and do a real local `hg convert`.

Comment: @Benju: That is completely wrong. I've regularly done this operation myself, so I know it works.